# How to prepare Hardhat project for cross-chain usages of the contracts

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, cross-chain

As the project and smart contracts with the project grow, developing and maintaining the project is hard. let's assume, all the contracts should deploy on several chains. How to structure these kinds of projects.
Any idea OR code example?

please vote me up if you have the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins like `hardhat-deploy`: https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy